# Is There a Way to Hide Builtin Network Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, axios, console

I'm using node.js to run my discord music bot, oops that's not the point...

The point is that I'm using `soundcloud-downloader` to download music, which uses `axios` I guess.

Whenever I type in a invalid url, its errors flood my entire console!

What I want is:
If the website does not exist, just print "Invalid URL!", don't print any details.

P.S. According to the information on the Internet, catch is useless...

Edited: Oops I forgot to show my code:

```
const scdl = require("soundcloud-downloader").default;
const fs = require("fs");

(async() => {
    scdl.getSetInfo("https://soundcloud.com/12345/67890" /* A nonexistent song URL */)
        .then((info) => {
            console.log(info);
        })
        .catch((reason) => {
            
        })
})();
```

The error I got:

```
(Even breaks stack overflow character limits...)

        _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
        [Symbol(res)]: TLSWrap {
          _parent: TCP {
            reading: [Getter/Setter],
            onconnection: null,
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          _parentWrap: undefined,
          _secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {} },
          reading: true,
          onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
          onhandshakestart: {},
          onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
          onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
          onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
          onerror: [Function: onerror],
          [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
        },
        [Symbol(verified)]: true,
        [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
        [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 315,
        [Symbol(kHandle)]: TLSWrap {
          _parent: TCP {
            reading: [Getter/Setter],
            onconnection: null,
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          _parentWrap: undefined,
          _secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {} },
          reading: true,
          onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
          onhandshakestart: {},
          onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
          onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
          onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
          onerror: [Function: onerror],
          [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
        },
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
        [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
        [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: {
          rejectUnauthorized: true,
          ciphers: 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA',
          checkServerIdentity: [Function: checkServerIdentity],
          minDHSize: 1024,
          maxRedirects: 21,
          maxBodyLength: 10485760,
          protocol: 'https:',
          path: null,
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4'
          },
          agent: undefined,
          agents: { http: undefined, https: undefined },
          auth: undefined,
          hostname: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
          port: 443,
          nativeProtocols: { 'http:': [Object], 'https:': [Object] },
          pathname: '/resolve',
          search: '?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F12345%2F67890&client_id=RMDIzNoU4QIzQsT3xq9J5TdxFFQlJvLY', 
          _defaultAgent: Agent {
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 2,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            defaultPort: 443,
            protocol: 'https:',
            options: [Object: null prototype],
            requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
            sockets: [Object: null prototype],
            freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
            keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
            keepAlive: false,
            maxSockets: Infinity,
            maxFreeSockets: 256,
            scheduling: 'lifo',
            maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
            totalSocketCount: 1,
            maxCachedSessions: 100,
            _sessionCache: [Object],
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
          },
          host: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
          noDelay: true,
          servername: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
          _agentKey: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::',
          encoding: null,
          singleUse: true
        }
      },
      _header: 'GET /resolve?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F12345%2F67890&client_id=RMDIzNoU4QIzQsT3xq9J5TdxFFQlJvLY HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.4\r\n' +
        'Host: api-v2.soundcloud.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: Agent {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          free: [Function (anonymous)],
          newListener: [Function: maybeEnableKeylog]
        },
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object: null prototype] { noDelay: true, path: null },
        requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
        sockets: [Object: null prototype] {
          'api-v2.soundcloud.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::': [ [TLSSocket] ]
        },
        freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        scheduling: 'lifo',
        maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
        totalSocketCount: 1,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: {
          map: {
            'soundcloud.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::': [Buffer [Uint8Array]],
            'a-v2.sndcdn.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::': [Buffer [Uint8Array]],
            'api-v2.soundcloud.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::': [Buffer [Uint8Array]]
          },
          list: [
            'soundcloud.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::',
            'a-v2.sndcdn.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::',
            'api-v2.soundcloud.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::'
          ]
        },
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
      },
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/resolve?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F12345%2F67890&client_id=RMDIzNoU4QIzQsT3xq9J5TdxFFQlJvLY',
      _ended: true,
      res: IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: ReadableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
          length: 0,
          pipes: [],
          flowing: true,
          ended: true,
          endEmitted: true,
          reading: false,
          constructed: true,
          sync: true,
          needReadable: false,
          emittedReadable: false,
          readableListening: false,
          resumeScheduled: false,
          errorEmitted: false,
          emitClose: true,
          autoDestroy: true,
          destroyed: true,
          errored: null,
          closed: true,
          closeEmitted: true,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          awaitDrainWriters: null,
          multiAwaitDrain: false,
          readingMore: true,
          dataEmitted: true,
          decoder: null,
          encoding: null,
          [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
        },
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function: handleStreamEnd] ],
          data: [Function: handleStreamData],
          error: [Function: handleStreamError]
        },
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: <ref *1> TLSSocket {
          _tlsOptions: {
            allowHalfOpen: undefined,
            pipe: false,
            secureContext: [SecureContext],
            isServer: false,
            requestCert: true,
            rejectUnauthorized: true,
            session: undefined,
            ALPNProtocols: undefined,
            requestOCSP: undefined,
            enableTrace: undefined,
            pskCallback: undefined,
            highWaterMark: undefined,
            onread: undefined,
            signal: undefined
          },
          _secureEstablished: true,
          _securePending: false,
          _newSessionPending: false,
          _controlReleased: true,
          secureConnecting: false,
          _SNICallback: null,
          servername: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
          alpnProtocol: false,
          authorized: true,
          authorizationError: null,
          encrypted: true,
          _events: [Object: null prototype] {
            close: [Array],
            end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
            newListener: [Function: keylogNewListener],
            secure: [Function: onConnectSecure],
            session: [Function (anonymous)],
            free: [Function: onFree],
            timeout: [Function: onTimeout],
            agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
            error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
            finish: [Function]
          },
          _eventsCount: 10,
          connecting: false,
          _hadError: false,
          _parent: null,
          _host: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
          _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
          _readableState: ReadableState {
            objectMode: false,
            highWaterMark: 16384,
            buffer: [BufferList],
            length: 0,
            pipes: [],
            flowing: true,
            ended: false,
            endEmitted: false,
            reading: true,
            constructed: true,
            sync: false,
            needReadable: true,
            emittedReadable: false,
            readableListening: false,
            resumeScheduled: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            emitClose: false,
            autoDestroy: true,
            destroyed: false,
            errored: null,
            closed: false,
            closeEmitted: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            awaitDrainWriters: null,
            multiAwaitDrain: false,
            readingMore: false,
            dataEmitted: true,
            decoder: null,
            encoding: null,
            [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
          },
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _writableState: WritableState {
            objectMode: false,
            highWaterMark: 16384,
            finalCalled: true,
            needDrain: false,
            ending: true,
            ended: true,
            finished: false,
            destroyed: false,
            decodeStrings: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            length: 0,
            writing: false,
            corked: 0,
            sync: false,
            bufferProcessing: false,
            onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
            writecb: null,
            writelen: 0,
            afterWriteTickInfo: null,
            buffered: [],
            bufferedIndex: 0,
            allBuffers: true,
            allNoop: true,
            pendingcb: 1,
            constructed: true,
            prefinished: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            emitClose: false,
            autoDestroy: true,
            errored: null,
            closed: false,
            closeEmitted: false,
            [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
          },
          allowHalfOpen: false,
          _sockname: null,
          _pendingData: null,
          _pendingEncoding: '',
          server: undefined,
          _server: null,
          ssl: TLSWrap {
            _parent: [TCP],
            _parentWrap: undefined,
            _secureContext: [SecureContext],
            reading: true,
            onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
            onhandshakestart: {},
            onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
            onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
            onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
            onerror: [Function: onerror],
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          _requestCert: true,
          _rejectUnauthorized: true,
          parser: null,
          _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
          [Symbol(res)]: TLSWrap {
            _parent: [TCP],
            _parentWrap: undefined,
            _secureContext: [SecureContext],
            reading: true,
            onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
            onhandshakestart: {},
            onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
            onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
            onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
            onerror: [Function: onerror],
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          [Symbol(verified)]: true,
          [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
          [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 315,
          [Symbol(kHandle)]: TLSWrap {
            _parent: [TCP],
            _parentWrap: undefined,
            _secureContext: [SecureContext],
            reading: true,
            onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
            onhandshakestart: {},
            onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
            onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
            onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
            onerror: [Function: onerror],
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
          [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
          [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
          [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
          [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
          [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
          [Symbol(connect-options)]: {
            rejectUnauthorized: true,
            ciphers: 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA',
            checkServerIdentity: [Function: checkServerIdentity],
            minDHSize: 1024,
            maxRedirects: 21,
            maxBodyLength: 10485760,
            protocol: 'https:',
            path: null,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: [Object],
            agent: undefined,
            agents: [Object],
            auth: undefined,
            hostname: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
            port: 443,
            nativeProtocols: [Object],
            pathname: '/resolve',
            search: '?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F12345%2F67890&client_id=RMDIzNoU4QIzQsT3xq9J5TdxFFQlJvLY',
            _defaultAgent: [Agent],
            host: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
            noDelay: true,
            servername: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
            _agentKey: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::',
            encoding: null,
            singleUse: true
          }
        },
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        rawHeaders: [
          'Content-Type',
          'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'Content-Length',
          '2',
          'Connection',
          'close',
          'Date',
          'Sun, 26 Mar 2023 09:27:14 GMT',
          'x-robots-tag',
          'noindex',
          'Cache-Control',
          'private, max-age=0',
          'referrer-policy',
          'no-referrer',
          'x-frame-options',
          'DENY',
          'x-content-type-options',
          'nosniff',
          'strict-transport-security',
          'max-age=63072000',
          'Server',
          'am/2',
          'Vary',
          'Origin',
          'X-Cache',
          'Error from cloudfront',
          'Via',
          '1.1 a55d34628b043ad0c3a5f728ad027e04.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
          'X-Amz-Cf-Pop',
          'TPE51-C1',
          'X-Amz-Cf-Id',
          'NZVD4xlV8MV3Ofdr040yjttQDV5xPXit0RAmUU1kZUh-w9AbH6DlBQ=='
        ],
        rawTrailers: [],
        aborted: false,
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 404,
        statusMessage: 'Not Found',
        client: <ref *1> TLSSocket {
          _tlsOptions: {
            allowHalfOpen: undefined,
            pipe: false,
            secureContext: [SecureContext],
            isServer: false,
            requestCert: true,
            rejectUnauthorized: true,
            session: undefined,
            ALPNProtocols: undefined,
            requestOCSP: undefined,
            enableTrace: undefined,
            pskCallback: undefined,
            highWaterMark: undefined,
            onread: undefined,
            signal: undefined
          },
          _secureEstablished: true,
          _securePending: false,
          _newSessionPending: false,
          _controlReleased: true,
          secureConnecting: false,
          _SNICallback: null,
          servername: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
          alpnProtocol: false,
          authorized: true,
          authorizationError: null,
          encrypted: true,
          _events: [Object: null prototype] {
            close: [Array],
            end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
            newListener: [Function: keylogNewListener],
            secure: [Function: onConnectSecure],
            session: [Function (anonymous)],
            free: [Function: onFree],
            timeout: [Function: onTimeout],
            agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
            error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
            finish: [Function]
          },
          _eventsCount: 10,
          connecting: false,
          _hadError: false,
          _parent: null,
          _host: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
          _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
          _readableState: ReadableState {
            objectMode: false,
            highWaterMark: 16384,
            buffer: [BufferList],
            length: 0,
            pipes: [],
            flowing: true,
            ended: false,
            endEmitted: false,
            reading: true,
            constructed: true,
            sync: false,
            needReadable: true,
            emittedReadable: false,
            readableListening: false,
            resumeScheduled: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            emitClose: false,
            autoDestroy: true,
            destroyed: false,
            errored: null,
            closed: false,
            closeEmitted: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            awaitDrainWriters: null,
            multiAwaitDrain: false,
            readingMore: false,
            dataEmitted: true,
            decoder: null,
            encoding: null,
            [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
          },
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _writableState: WritableState {
            objectMode: false,
            highWaterMark: 16384,
            finalCalled: true,
            needDrain: false,
            ending: true,
            ended: true,
            finished: false,
            destroyed: false,
            decodeStrings: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            length: 0,
            writing: false,
            corked: 0,
            sync: false,
            bufferProcessing: false,
            onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
            writecb: null,
            writelen: 0,
            afterWriteTickInfo: null,
            buffered: [],
            bufferedIndex: 0,
            allBuffers: true,
            allNoop: true,
            pendingcb: 1,
            constructed: true,
            prefinished: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            emitClose: false,
            autoDestroy: true,
            errored: null,
            closed: false,
            closeEmitted: false,
            [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
          },
          allowHalfOpen: false,
          _sockname: null,
          _pendingData: null,
          _pendingEncoding: '',
          server: undefined,
          _server: null,
          ssl: TLSWrap {
            _parent: [TCP],
            _parentWrap: undefined,
            _secureContext: [SecureContext],
            reading: true,
            onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
            onhandshakestart: {},
            onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
            onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
            onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
            onerror: [Function: onerror],
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          _requestCert: true,
          _rejectUnauthorized: true,
          parser: null,
          _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
          [Symbol(res)]: TLSWrap {
            _parent: [TCP],
            _parentWrap: undefined,
            _secureContext: [SecureContext],
            reading: true,
            onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
            onhandshakestart: {},
            onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
            onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
            onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
            onerror: [Function: onerror],
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          [Symbol(verified)]: true,
          [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
          [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 315,
          [Symbol(kHandle)]: TLSWrap {
            _parent: [TCP],
            _parentWrap: undefined,
            _secureContext: [SecureContext],
            reading: true,
            onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
            onhandshakestart: {},
            onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
            onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
            onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
            onerror: [Function: onerror],
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
          [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
          [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
          [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
          [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
          [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
          [Symbol(connect-options)]: {
            rejectUnauthorized: true,
            ciphers: 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA',
            checkServerIdentity: [Function: checkServerIdentity],
            minDHSize: 1024,
            maxRedirects: 21,
            maxBodyLength: 10485760,
            protocol: 'https:',
            path: null,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: [Object],
            agent: undefined,
            agents: [Object],
            auth: undefined,
            hostname: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
            port: 443,
            nativeProtocols: [Object],
            pathname: '/resolve',
            search: '?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F12345%2F67890&client_id=RMDIzNoU4QIzQsT3xq9J5TdxFFQlJvLY',
            _defaultAgent: [Agent],
            host: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
            noDelay: true,
            servername: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
            _agentKey: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::',
            encoding: null,
            singleUse: true
          }
        },
        _consuming: false,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Circular *2],
        responseUrl: 'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F12345%2F67890&client_id=RMDIzNoU4QIzQsT3xq9J5TdxFFQlJvLY',
        redirects: [],
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHeaders)]: {
          'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'content-length': '2',
          connection: 'close',
          date: 'Sun, 26 Mar 2023 09:27:14 GMT',
          'x-robots-tag': 'noindex',
          'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
          'referrer-policy': 'no-referrer',
          'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
          'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
          'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000',
          server: 'am/2',
          vary: 'Origin',
          'x-cache': 'Error from cloudfront',
          via: '1.1 a55d34628b043ad0c3a5f728ad027e04.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
          'x-amz-cf-pop': 'TPE51-C1',
          'x-amz-cf-id': 'NZVD4xlV8MV3Ofdr040yjttQDV5xPXit0RAmUU1kZUh-w9AbH6DlBQ=='
        },
        [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 32,
        [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
        [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
      },
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: Writable {
        _writableState: WritableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          finalCalled: false,
          needDrain: false,
          ending: false,
          ended: false,
          finished: false,
          destroyed: false,
          decodeStrings: true,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          length: 0,
          writing: false,
          corked: 0,
          sync: true,
          bufferProcessing: false,
          onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
          writecb: null,
          writelen: 0,
          afterWriteTickInfo: null,
          buffered: [],
          bufferedIndex: 0,
          allBuffers: true,
          allNoop: true,
          pendingcb: 0,
          constructed: true,
          prefinished: false,
          errorEmitted: false,
          emitClose: true,
          autoDestroy: true,
          errored: null,
          closed: false,
          closeEmitted: false,
          [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
        },
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          response: [Function: handleResponse],
          error: [Function: handleRequestError]
        },
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: {
          maxRedirects: 21,
          maxBodyLength: 10485760,
          protocol: 'https:',
          path: '/resolve?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F12345%2F67890&client_id=RMDIzNoU4QIzQsT3xq9J5TdxFFQlJvLY',
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4'
          },
          agent: undefined,
          agents: { http: undefined, https: undefined },
          auth: undefined,
          hostname: 'api-v2.soundcloud.com',
          port: null,
          nativeProtocols: { 'http:': [Object], 'https:': [Object] },
          pathname: '/resolve',
          search: '?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F12345%2F67890&client_id=RMDIzNoU4QIzQsT3xq9J5TdxFFQlJvLY'  
        },
        _ended: true,
        _ending: true,
        _redirectCount: 0,
        _redirects: [],
        _requestBodyLength: 0,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
        _currentRequest: [Circular *2],
        _currentUrl: 'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F12345%2F67890&client_id=RMDIzNoU4QIzQsT3xq9J5TdxFFQlJvLY',
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
      },
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
        accept: [ 'Accept', 'application/json, text/plain, */*' ],
        'user-agent': [ 'User-Agent', 'axios/0.21.4' ],
        host: [ 'Host', 'api-v2.soundcloud.com' ]
      },
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: {}
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Comment: Add the relevant code that creates the issue. Just an error is not helpful in providing a solution.

Comment: There is no such builtin logging in node.js. It might be done by the library. See its documentation on how to disable that or open an issue in their bugtracker to make it configurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it.

Since `soundcloud-downloader` is an old project...
And its docs are even "404 not found"!

I don't think there's a way to disable it...
So I force disabled it by digging through the internal files to find the error logging part and fix it.

I don't think this is the correct solution :(
But at least it's solved.